# Discretize differential Equation numerical methods

Tags: numerical-methods

I don't know how to approach this question by numerical methods, any help will be appreciated:

Discretize the following differential equation using central finite difference formulation:

$$y''(x)+y'(x)+2y=0$$

Comment: Do you have the boundary conditions?

Comment: why a numerical solution, there is an explicit one

Comment: Nope, there is no boundary conditions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, I have an Numerical Methods (course) exam on Monday, and its in the homework.

Comment: @MuradNazari You need to have the boundary conditions. Anyway, replace $y''$ by $\frac{y_{n+1}-2y_n+y_{n-1}}{h^2}$, $y'$ by $\frac{y_{n+1}-y_{n-1}}{2h}$ and $y$ by $y_n$. You will get a tridiagonal system for n=0,..,M. Once you obtain the boundary conditions, substitute into the system and you can solve via Thomas Algorithm.

Comment: M is dependent on h, which is the stepsize. Suppose you have boundary conditions for the problem. y(a)=..., y(b)=.... Then M=(b-a)/h.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

You will need three points $y_0,  y_1, y_{-1}$

Replace each term with the function of the points required to calculate the term. For instance, I'm guessing you are supposed to use $y'(x)=\frac{y_1 - y_{-1}}{2\Delta x}$

The formula for $y''$ also only takes 3 points.

Solve for $y_1$